# EWS FileAttachment without FileName

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS to recieve mails and import them to our CRM-System. In 99% of the mails everything works fine. But no I have the problem, that some fileattachments dont tell me the filename.

here's an example of my code.

```
Item item = Item.Bind("id"); //id should be replaced by a leagle id

PropertySet ps = PropertyHelper.GetFullLoadItemPropertySet(m_Item.GetType()); 
//the propertyset is a manually created set with all relevant properties.

item.Load(ps)M

foreach (Attachment att in item.Attachments)
{                                    {
    FileAttachment fa = att as FileAttachment;
    if (fa != null)
    {
        fa.Load();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fa.FileName))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

If I look at the same mail using a little vba-code the attachment has a filename, which is displayed in outlook.

```
Dim mail As MailItem

Set mail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1)

debug.Print mail.Attachments.Item(0).FileName
```

Does anyone have an idea why outlook gets the correct filename, but EWS is telling me that the attachment has no filename?

Comment: Does EWS contain the proper `DisplayName` via the [`Attachment.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.name%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property?

Comment: Yes. In the current Case Attachment.Name shows "Service Bericht", which is exactly what Outlook shows in the DisplayName-property. But I can't access any value that show's the value of the FileName-Property in Outlook. I should say, that these mails were created by a service and not created manually in Outlook.

Comment: Outlook is itself not using EWS to talk to the Exchange Server, it is using MAPI.  Sometimes this will lead to small differences (like this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the `Attachment` items you get from EWS are actual `FileAttachment` items.
Add a check for the attachment type.

```
foreach (Attachment att in item.Attachments)
{              
    if (att is FileAttachment fa)
    {
        // Do something with 'fa'
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileAttachment` inherits from `Attachment`, so any `Attachment` can be converted to `FileAttachment`. That doesn't mean the original object type was `FileAttachment`. Its value after conversion will not be null, which makes `if (fa != null)` meaningless.

Comment: >> FileAttachment inherits from Attachment, so any Attachment can be converted to FileAttachment. - this is not true. Only vise versa is true - any `FileAttachment` can be converted to `Attachment`. So, them you are using this statement: `att as FileAttachment`, if `att` is not a `FileAttachement, result will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing EWS sources shows that FileAttachment.FileName property is only populated when the attachment gets saved to local disk with .Load method.

Answer (score 0):

I used the emailMessage schema in a similar system and haven't noticed this issue, maybe the below will help:

```
//creates an object that will represent the desired mailbox
Mailbox mb = new Mailbox(common.strInboxURL);

//creates a folder object that will point to inbox fold
FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mb);

//this will bind the mailbox you're looking for using your service instance
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder inbox = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.Bind(service, fid);

SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));


// exclude any silly returned emails
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, "Undeliverable")));
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, "Out of Office")));

ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);

// This results in a FindItem operation call to EWS.
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(fid, searchFilterCollection, view);

if (results.Count() > 0)
   {

   // set the prioperties we need for the entire result set
   view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(
   BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
   ItemSchema.Subject,
   ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
   ItemSchema.DisplayTo, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients,
   EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead,
   EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, ItemSchema.MimeContent,
   EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.Sender,
   ItemSchema.Body) { RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text };

   // load the properties for the entire batch
   service.LoadPropertiesForItems(results, view.PropertySet);

    forech (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
        {

        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
            {
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
```